# equation for the beta function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

Using only the definition

$$B(x, y) = \int_0^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}dt$$

for the Beta function, proof the term: $(x + y)B(x + 1, y) = xB(x, y) \space\space \forall x, y > 0$ .

Thanks in advance! I've tried rewriting the expression and getting the (x + y) of the first term into the integral, but that didn't lead anywhere so far.

Answer (score 2):

First note that

$$\begin{align}
B(x+1,y)+B(x,y+1)&=\int_0^1 \left(t^x(1-t)^{y-1}+t^{x-1}(1-t)^y\right) dt\\\\
&=\int_0^1\left( t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}\left[t+(1-t)\right] \right)dt\\\\
&=B(x,y)
\end{align}$$

Then,

$$\begin{align}
yB(x+1,y)&= y\int_0^1 t^{x} (1-t)^{y-1}dt\\\\
&=-\int_0^1 t^x \frac{d(1-t)^{y}}{dt} dt \,\,\,\,\ \dots \text{using} \,\,\frac{d(1-t)^{y}}{dt}=-y\,(1-t)^{y-1}\\\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{dt^{x}}{dt}(1-t)^{y}dt\,\,\,\,\ \dots \text{using integration by parts with}\,\, u=t^x\,\,\text{and}\,\,v=(1-t)^y\\\\
&=x\int_0^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y}dt \\\\
&=xB(x,y+1)\\\\
&=x\left(B(x,y)-B(x+1,y)\right)
\end{align}$$

whereupon we get the desired result!

Comment: Okay, that was very helpful, thanks. Is there a way (using, again, only the definition of the Beta function from above, this just-shown property and maybe the symmetry of the Beta function) to show that: $B(x, y) = \frac{(n - 1)!(m - 1)!}{(n + m - 1)!} \space \forall n, m \in \mathbb{N}$ ? Yes the Beta function is closely related to the Gamma function from all that I know, but can this be shown using only these definitions, and without using the Gamma function?

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  On you new question, let me have a look and I'll revert.  I hope I was able to give you the best answer I could.

Comment: Also, could you please elaborate how you got to the term $-\int_0^1 t^x \frac{d(1-t)^{y}}{dt} dt$ and the step thereafter? I know about partial integration, but I can't quite see what you did there. Everything else seems logical, but I don't quite get these two steps.

Comment: OK.  I just added the notes after the equations. Please let me know how I can improve it. I just want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: Okay, thanks again, now I understand. Did you have any luck with the second equation I wrote in the comment so far?

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad that you've got it now!  And I'm really glad I could help.  I have not yet pursued the other equation.

Answer (score 0):

Show that from the definition of a Gamma function:

$$
\Gamma(x) = \int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt\,.
$$

that $\Gamma(x) \Gamma(y) = \Gamma(x+y) B(x,y)$. Then recall that $\Gamma(x+1) = x\Gamma(x)$ and the result will follow.